# Python Distance Matrix from csv file

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, distance

I currently have a csv file with the name, latitude and logitude of 2000 different locations. I need to use Python to create a distance matrix for each location to another location. I am extremely new and have no idea where to begin. Please help

```
`from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
import csv

with open('DBN.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in readCSV:
    for i in readCSV:
        distances =[]
        lon1 = float(row[1])
        lat1= float(row[2])
        lon2= float(i[1])
        lat2= float(i[2])
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
        r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
        dist = c * r
        distances.append(dist)
        print distances`
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is your problem more related to Python, or more mathematical? (in other words, do you have an idea of how to solve this problem on paper for a couple of locations?)

Comment: It is purely related to Python, I will upload my code so far but unfortunately I cannot get it to create a distance matrix

Comment: You'll have to specify a bit more exactly what your problem is when you say you cannot create the distance matrix. Do you get any errors, or does it just not do what you expect?